# Editing maven repo pulled from github

Tags: java, android, git, maven, github

There is a maven repo on github that I am using in my android project. I want to modify one package in it.

I have downloaded it locally and replaced the gradle.build call, but how do I actually modify the package (.jar) I am interested in? The repo doesn't come with a pom.xml file, though there are .pom files in the subdirectories.

Here is the actual repo: https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you would modify any .jar. Jars are just .zip files, so you can modify and edit its contents, if you really want to.

Note though that maven repo includes both .md5 and .sha1 files to prevent just the kind of tampering you're suggesting, so you'd need to remove those if you want it to go through.

I would rather just create a new version in its own folder and not edit the existing ones, if possible. You could then have a custom maven version for it, clearly signaled that it's a custom one, and use that in your app.

So for example now you have [this](https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/tree/master/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9):

```
com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.pom
com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar.md5
com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar.sha1
com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.pom.md5
com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.pom.sha1
```

And if you would edit it, you'd create new version beside it

```
com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.pom
com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar.md5
com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar.sha1
com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.pom.md5
com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.pom.sha1
com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9-customized/jsr305-1.3.9-customized.jar
com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9-customized/jsr305-1.3.9-customized.pom
```

So you can refer to your own version in your android application *using* the repository:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.9-customized</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Sorry I know this was a very basic question; I know how to edit a jar, but have never touched maven.
So I just make a new maven repository, even though the pom file is missing from the one I have?

Comment: @niraj267 added an example, maybe that clarifies. There are no pom files of maven repositories themselves, they are just storages for pom files + artifacts of different projects.

Comment: Thank you; I was misunderstanding what the pom files were for